# Leaflet - Interactive Map - add event

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet

I'm struggling with 2 small problems with my example map with bicycle routes.

1.At the moment my map works like this:

When you mouse over route it highlights (this is good).

When you mouse out route it dehighlights (this is also good).

When you click on a route it highlights and zooms to feature (this is good).

And here is problematic part: When you click anywhere on a map (not the route) the route should dehighlight so it looks like default view without any highlight but it doesn't happen.
How can I achieve that? I tried map.on event but I'm not sure where to put it in the code.

2.Is there any way to offset the geojson lines? I would like to put them right under the dotted lines. I tried setting an offset in my style but it doesn't work.

Here's a link to working map

http://mapaszlakow.eu/interactive.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: hey, if this question is closed and my answer was helpful please mark as accepted ;)

Answer (score 1):

As for the first part of your question, to dehighlight your route when clicking outside of it on map - you can approach this with `map.on(..)` function for geojson:

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(szlaki, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      ...
      }
    }); 

    map.on({
      'click': function(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(layer);
        info.update();
        selected = null;
      }
    });

  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/LWbpqP

---

About the second question, did you try [**Leaflet.PolylineOffset plugin**](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset) ?

Comment: That did the job but how can I also hide the info box with route name? The one appearing in right top corner? I wil investigate the offset plugin, thanks!

Comment: @Voyteck I edited my answer here and in codepen. To reset your infobox I added `info.update();` within `map.on()` function. pozdrowienia ;)

Comment: There is still a small bug, I'll try to explain. When you click a route so it get's highlighted, then you click on map to dehighlight it and after that you mouse over the same route it gets highlighted permanently. It should only highlight when mouse over. I hope you get me :)

Comment: sorry for bothering you, any chance you could help me with this small issue? :)

Comment: Sure I can try to help :) I updated codepen and answer above, please test it. I added `selected = null;`

Comment: Superb.Thanks a lot!